# How to scrape oauth secured api using scrapy

Tags: python, oauth, web-scraping, scrapy

When scraping simple sites, a simple GET or POST request with a few parameters is enough to get the data from the site.

However, when scraping an oauth-secured site, in addition to the url-specific parameters it's necessary to send oauth parameters (`oauth_consumer_key, oauth_signature, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_token`)

How could scrapy be configured so that  `scrapy.Request` automatically includes those parameters? (obviosly after supplying api keys, etc)

If that can't be done, is it possible to extract those parameters from a request created from another library (like `oauth2`) and put them into a scrapy request?

Comment: Did you try reading their documentation?  The answer probably lies there

Comment: @touchmyboomboom there are [no search results](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/search.html?q=oauth&check_keywords=yes&area=default) for the latest version of the documentation

Comment: There's nothing  builtin in Scrapy. Here are some pointers on what the community has come up with: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/compare/master...juanriaza:oauth-draft?expand=1 , https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scrapy-users/EUzuuy6oaeE/7tmZBsJLDAAJ